# How to run a random audio file Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my first Chrome extension, one that will play a random audio file of the ones I have in my folder when clicked. I tried doing this, however it didn't work. I have four files currently, each installed in the same folder, numbered 1-4 (I had tried to use the link provided prior to asking) and would like to play a random one each click. Currently, I can get one clip to play. Coding below:

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "NAME",
  "description": "DESC",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

and here is my current popup.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <style>
      body {min-width: 250px;}
    </style>
    <script src='popup.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <div id="typedUrl_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally, the popup.js

```
var myAudio = new Audio();
myAudio.src = "1.mp3"; 
myAudio.play();
```

As said prior, I can get it to run that one file, but I want it to randomize them 1-4. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1527803)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var randomNumberFrom1to4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
var myAudio = new Audio();
myAudio.src = randomNumberFrom1to4  + ".mp3"; 
myAudio.play();
```

Comment: And if I were to add more audio clips, would I replace all the 4s with however many there are at that point?